# Jekyll build breaks on GitLab, bundler issue

Tags: gitlab, jekyll, bundler

I have a Jekyll website hosted on GitLab. Since upgrading to the latest version, 3.8.5 my builds break and I get the following message

```
$ bundle install --path vendor  
You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Is there a way to update Bundler on GitLab or some other solution to solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just wanted to update this question if anyone else have this issue. I wasn't able to update Bundler but deleting Gemfile.lock file fixed the issue.